# How to validate multiple forms at the same time

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-redux, formik

I have a very big form splitted in 6 forms (each one rendered in a component and accessible through tabs) with only one submit button (on the parent component of the 6 forms). Each form has its own validation schema (using Yup) working (it's working on input change and blur). All data is obtained from and updated to a Redux state. An action creator is dispatched when submit button is clicked and relevant data is sent to a server, but I need to check (before dispatch the action) if all fields are valid (in the parent component).

I'll put some code in CodeSandbox soon, but I'm asking before the code is ready because I'm in a hurry with that functionality and maybe someone know how to solve my problem.

Comment: Please add the code. But if the parent component need to check if the form is valid, maybe you should have only one form (lift the state up) or store the form errors so the parent can see it.

Answer (score 0):

[Rough implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/subform-components-kc3kd)

---

One way would be to structure your application so that you have one `<form>` element on a top-level component and have all 6 subforms be children to that `<form>`. You would need to remove the `<form>` tags from all 6 of your subforms.

A caveat to this approach, however, is that you can't group your inputs by subform *(or at least I don't think you can)*.

It might be possible to tag each input name with a prefix, such as `form-one-...`, `form-two-...`, filter through your inputs in `handleSubmit()`, and categorize them by subform.

Then, you can send each subform's input values to get validated.

---

```js
class MainForm extends Component {
    handleSubmit = event => {
        const { /*...get inputs here */ } = event.target

        // Do some work with data.

        // Make a POST request to API.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <SubformOne />
                <SubformTwo />
                <SubformThree />
                <SubformFour />
                <SubformFive />
                <SubformSix />

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: That is nice, but I have a working software and need to add just a functionality, without making big changes or losing a lot a time.

Comment: The creator of Formik advises that nested forms are not valid in HTML

Comment: Thank you @SebastianPatten, I should choose my words more carefully when explaining. Each subform does not use a `<form>` tag. Instead, each subform houses the various inputs, selects, etc. I have updated my CodeSandbox link to depict my approach.